# Problem sending array data from matlab to arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, matlab

I've two LEDs connected to the arduino uno's pin 12 and 13. I want to control the LEDs independently from the MATLAB serial command.

Here is my MATLAB serial command from where I'm sending char array

```
s = serial('COM4','BaudRate',9600);
fopen(s);
output = [2,1];
data = char(output);
fprintf(s,'%d',data);
fprintf(s);
```

And this is my Arduino code to receive char array

```
char d[4];
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      d[i] = Serial.read();
    }
    d1 = d[0]-'0';
    if (d1 == 1)
   {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    }
  else if (d1 == 2)
    {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    }
    d2 = d[1]-'0';
    if (d2 == 1)
   {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
     digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    }
  else if (d2 == 2)
    {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

The MATLAB command is intended to keep the LED on for the given seconds. When I tried this code for one LED(sending only single char) it worked fine. But when I tried it for two LEDs it turns on only LED connected to pin 12 twice.

Eg:
MATLAB command output = [2,1], turns on LED(pin 12) for 2 sec and then for 1 sec but I want it should be to turn on LED(pin 12) for 2 sec and LED (pin 13) for 1 sec.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: If you look at the serial data sent in a terminal what is it? If the serial data is "2,1" then you want `d2 = d[2]-'0';` not `d2 = d[1]-'0';` Also instead of a load of if statements wouldn't be easier to get the time by multiplying the value by 1000? `digitalWrite(12, HIGH);delay(d1*1000);`